# Authentication fails when add UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3.2.5. Bellow is my security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider ap;
    @Autowired
    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter myFilter;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
            .httpBasic();
        http.addFilterAfter(myFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationProvider ap, AuthenticationManagerBuilder amb) throws Exception {
        amb.authenticationProvider(ap);
    }

}
```

and here are some of my declared beans:

```
@Bean
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter restApiAuthenticationFilter() {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
    return filter;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = new LinkedList<AuthenticationProvider>();
    providers.add(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    ProviderManager pm = new ProviderManager(providers);
    return pm;
}
```

Now the problem is that if I add `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to spring security, the authenticatio fails, otherwise it goes well. Any recommandations on this issue?
I'm getting this in log files:

> 2015-01-14 16:03:55,548 [io-8080-exec-54] DEBUG ProviderManager                - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
>
> 2015-01-14 16:03:55,557 [io-8080-exec-54] DEBUG EntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
>
> 2015-01-14 16:03:55,672 [io-8080-exec-54] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils      - Closing JPA EntityManager
>
> 2015-01-14 16:03:55,772 [io-8080-exec-54] DEBUG DaoAuthenticationProvider      - User '' not found

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter in Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938909/adding-custom-usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter-filter-in-spring)

Comment: @M.Deinum Deleted the one you linked. This post solves both problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was regarding my user name and password parameters. I declared the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter bean like that and the problem got solved:

```
@Bean
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter restApiAuthenticationFilter() {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filter.setUsernameParameter("username");
    filter.setPasswordParameter("password");
    filter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the `formLogin` for that? What is the difference and why would you need 2  `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. Your current config is the same as what `formLogin` does.

Comment: I needed a custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticaionFilter`. Just tried like that for simplifiaction. Thank.